# Calculate total subscription end date from multiple subscription end dates in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

Today is 2014-11-16.

I got these three dates in the future but I want them to be only one date instead.

```
2014-12-15 21:27:12
2014-12-15 21:32:20
2014-12-16 12:22:09
```

I want to get the total end date from today. That would be aproximately three month into the future but how can i calculate it to be the same date each time from the three dates above?

How can this be achieved with PHP's DateTime and DateInterval classes?

Comment: Perhaps reading the manual pages might help

Comment: Hi Ed. Thank you for your comment. I already did that but I couldn't figure out why the total enddate kept on increasing when i added the DateInterval (from now to the end date) of each subscription. This wasn't a problem when I added just one DateInterval.

Comment: so what will be the end goal? its unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
$dateTimeObject=new DateTime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('2014-12-16 12:22:09')));
//to get diff with now
$diff = $dateTimeObject->diff(new DateTime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s')));
```

Then,

```
//to get diff months
echo $diff->m;
//to get diff hours
echo $diff->h;
//to get diff minutes
echo $diff->i;
```

And so on.

It is highly recommended to take a look at the PHP's **[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)** official document.

*Note that, `DateTime` is available on `PHP` >=5.2.0*